# Are agreement statistics suitable for comparing ratings produced by the same rater on different experiments?

Tags: biostatistics, ordinal-data, agreement-statistics

I am interested in comparing the results of a single statistical test applied separately to two different datasets. My test produces lists of p-values and estimated effect sizes for the features of a dataset. I'd like to compare the output of the test on one dataset to its outputs on another to assess whether or not the outputs are "close" to one another.

Are inter-rater reliabilty metrics suitable for this? I have typically seen them for comparing two different models applied to the same dataset, i.e. the p-values are for similar hypotheses with different assumptions on the null.

The domain I'm in is differential expression analysis - I'd like to compare, for instance, the set of Wilcoxson rank-sum pvalues for genes from one experiment to a separate set of Wilcoxson rank-sum pvalues for genes from a different experiment.